# Chrome App Popup On Notification

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, chromium

I'm new to Chrome Apps, however I did successfully get my app to work with GCM. I'm so happy! What I would like the app to do however, is open a popup window when the user gets a notification. I'm making it a video chat app. Please Any Help at all would be greatly appreciated! This code that I have is currently not working for popups, tabs or anything of the sort... :(

> background.js

```
    // Returns a new notification ID used in the notification.
function getNotificationId() {
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9007199254740992) + 1;
  return id.toString();
}

function messageReceived(message) {
  // A message is an object with a data property that
  // consists of key-value pairs.

  // Concatenate all key-value pairs to form a display string.
  var messageString = "";
  for (var key in message.data) {
    if (messageString != "")
      messageString += ", "
    messageString += key + ":" + message.data[key];
  }
  console.log("Message received: " + messageString);

  // Pop up a notification to show the GCM message.
  chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: 'GCM Message',
    iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
    type: 'basic',
    message: messageString
  }, function() {});


chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com"});

}

var registerWindowCreated = false;

function firstTimeRegistration() {
  chrome.storage.local.get("registered", function(result) {
    // If already registered, bail out.
    if (result["registered"])
      return;

    registerWindowCreated = true;
    chrome.app.window.create(
      "register.html",
      {  width: 500,
         height: 400,
         frame: 'chrome'
      },
      function(appWin) {}
    );
  });
}

// Set up a listener for GCM message event.
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);

// Set up listeners to trigger the first time registration.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(firstTimeRegistration);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(firstTimeRegistration);
```

> Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "GCM Notifications",
  "description": "Chrome platform app.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.3",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["gcm", "storage", "notifications", "tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "icons": { "128": "gcm_128.png" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.notifications.create` should appear outside the browser. I can't see anything wrong with the call you made, though. We need to determine if you're not breaking the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy)

> In Chrome Apps, due to a strict Content Security Policy these URLs must point to a local resource or use a [blob or data URL](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external). Use a 3:2 ratio for your image; otherwise a black border frames the image.

Additional references you can look at is the official [notification sample repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/rich-notifications) as well as how to [integrate notification with GCM](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/gcm-notifications).

Comment: Well, I'm receiving notifications, except I'm trying to open a new browser window(pop-up) when I receive the notification. I'm not sure about Content Security Policies or anything like that - I'm new to Chrome Apps. If you can kindly give me a brief demonstration on local resources? It's very hard to find helpful information on Chrome Apps - at least with trying to do what I'm doing.

Comment: Then I think you should call the [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) method inside the `creationCallback` function. Currently its just an empty function, try to move it and hopefully that works.

Comment: Also, you can check out the GoogleChrome github, they're helpful to check out how to implement one or know if you're missing something.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I'm familiar with the GoogleChrome github, that's how I got GCM to work. There isn't anything on there for adding a pop-up though. It might be something I need to figure out myself. =( If you have any other idea's please let me know.